# Loading check certs from memory

Tags: c

I want replace *SSL_CTX_verify_locations(X509, "cert.pem", 0)* function by any other that load certs from memory, I tried

```
X509_STORE* store = X509_STORE_new();
X509* temp;
BIO* mem;
unsigned char CAPEM[] = {0x13, ..., ...};
store = SSL_CTX_get_cert_store(SSL_CONTEXT)
mem = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)CAPEM, sizeof(CAPEM));
PEM_read_bio_X509(mem, &temp, 0, 0)
X509_STORE_add_cert(store, temp)
SSL_CTX_set_verify(SSL_CONTEXT, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, 0);
```

and

```
SSL_CTX_add_extra_chain_cert(SSL_CONTEXT, temp)
```

I'm using openssl 1.0.2, Thanks

Comment: Show some [MCVE] please

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to create certificate store with `X509_STORE_new()` and then add certificates to it using `X509_STORE_add_cert()`

Comment: Nothing, Error server side (tlv1 alert unkonw ca).